# How to add additional tab in the User Profile page using views

Tags: 7, views, users, flags

I have installed the flag module and it comes with some 2 views that are added to the list of views. One of them will stick to the user page as an additional tab and when clicked will show a list of all the nodes that were flagged by that specific user being previewed. So far so good.

The problem is that in my website I don't use the path "user/**uid**" for the user pages. I use the path (example) "somethingelse/**uid**". When I enter the view and edit the path for this tab page with "somethingelse/**uid**", save the view and reload the user page... the tab with the list of items flagged by the current user disappears completely.

How can I bring that tab back on the user page? I am on Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

`somethingelse/<uid>` is a path alias for `user/<uid>`. When you set the path for a view, you need not to use path aliases.